# How to use interceptors in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, axios

I`m having trouble using axios in NextJS simply because the interceptors are called multiple times with just 1 request or response.

I just put the interceptors inside the _app.tsx Component and they are working. The only problem is that they are being called more than once.

I appreciate if you can help me!

Here's my code:

```
// ** Axios Configs
  axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3333';

  // ** Request Interceptor
  axios.interceptors.request.use(
    (config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
      console.log('ok request');

      // ** Get token from localStorage
      const accessToken = window.localStorage.getItem(authConfig.storageTokenKeyName)

      // ** If token is present add it to request's Authorization Header
      if (accessToken) {
        // ** eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
        if (config.headers)
          config.headers.Authorization = accessToken;
      }
      return config;
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log('ok, errors 1')
      return Promise.reject(error)
    }
  );

  // ** Add request/response interceptor
  axios.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      console.log('response >', response)
      return response
    },
    (error) => {
      const { config, response } = error;

      if (response && response?.status === 401) {
        router.push('/401');
      } else if (
        response?.data &&
        (
          response?.status === 500 ||
          response?.status === 400
        )
      ) {
        if (typeof response.data?.error === 'string') {
          toast.error(response.data?.error, { duration: 3000 })
        } else {
          toast.error('Houve um erro desconhecido. Tente novamente ou contate o suporte!', { duration: 3000 })
        }
      } else if (response?.data && response?.status === 409) {
        if (response.data.message) {
          response.data.message.map((item: { message: string }) => {
            toast.error(item.message, { duration: 3000 })
          })
        } else {
          toast.error(response.data.error, { duration: 3000 })
        }
      } else if (error?.code === "ERR_NETWORK") {
        toast.error('Ops! Houve de conexão. Tente novamente.', { duration: 3000 })
      } else {
        toast.error('Ops! Houve um erro desconhecido ao executar esta ação', { duration: 3000 })
      }
      console.log('ok, errors 2')
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );
```

I've tried moving the interceptors to the index.tsx, but faced the same thing

Comment: Where exactly do you call this file?

Comment: This code is in the _app.tsx component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem for me was that the interceptors were accumulating through the app.

So the solution that worked for me while fixing this issue was to eject the interceptor everytime that the component was going to unmount

```
var myInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use(...)    
interceptors.request.eject(myInterceptor)
```